# Using C based Python modules in zipped Python directories

Tags: python, python-cryptography

I recently learned about Python's ability to run a zipped directory and I set out to try it. 
This works quite well for small pure Python programs I tested. However, once I moved to much larger applications using C based libraries things become though. I have an application which uses Cryptography, and I can't get this to work. 
Here is how to produces the error I am seeing:

This is the `__main__` file:

```
# cat __main__.py 
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
backend = default_backend()
key = os.urandom(32)
iv = os.urandom(16)
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
ct = encryptor.update(b"a secret message") + encryptor.finalize()
decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
print(decryptor.update(ct) + decryptor.finalize())
```

And this is how to create the zipped file:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
rm -R build/
mkdir build
cp __main__.py build/
pip2 install -v -U --no-cache-dir --target=build/ cryptography
cd build/
zip -r ../test.pyz .
```

Now I got a file `test.pyz` which I am trying to run and I get the following error:

```
$ python2 test.pyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "test.pyz/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 35, in default_backend
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 22, in _available_backends
  File "/tmp/pip-build-3JjP5c/setuptools/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/x509/base.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/x509/extensions.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpZjvIXl/lib/python/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 9, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _constant_time
```

Does anyone have an idea how to work with C based modules in zip files?

#### Update

As suggested, I tried packaging the application with zipapp and run it with 
Python3, but I'm still seeing that same error.

#### Update 2

Here is again a complete log of my failure:

```
$ pip3.5 install -v -U --no-cache-dir --target=build/ pycryptodome
$ cat build/__main__.py 

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def main():
    print(bla)

$ python3.5 -m zipapp build
$ python3.5 build.pyz 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "build.pyz/__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "build.pyz/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 78, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load

bal = AES

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "build.pyz/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py", line 46, in <module>
  File "build.pyz/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 168, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb'
```

No idea how to use C based modules inside zipped directories ...

Comment: FWIW using  zipapp to create the pyz works for me, https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html

Comment: This is fine, but my application needs to work with Python2 for at least another year :-( Which means I can't really on packaging with Python3.5.

Comment: The source code is there so it is only a matter of replicating the logic, https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/zipapp.py `pip2 install pathlib` and you are good to go

Comment: See my update. This is something which does not have to do with my bash script

Comment: I have used your bash script and https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/zipapp.py under python2 and 3, your bash approach always gives the same error but the zipapp logic works fine under both 2 and 3. The only thing to run the script under python2 was install pathlib

Comment: Would you be kind and write the exact steps you are taking? I have 0 success so far.

Comment: I will add the code to pastebin when I get back on my comp